# Drink driving ban in the UK applying for a Russian visa

Tags: visas, russia, applications, criminal-records

I want to go to Russia for a short holiday.  I was arrested for drink driving just over a year ago and was banned for 4 years.  Do I need to declare this on my visa application form?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the application asks about convictions. Drink driving is a criminal offence under section 5(1)(a) of the Road Traffic Act 1988. You’ll also need to provide a Police Report.